# How to get code from google code?

Tags: google-code

I would like to check out code from google code using the source,

```
http://imedia.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/imedia-read-only
```

How would I do this? I am using a Mac with Xcode and have a copy of "Versions".

Thank you.

Comment: Just use the svn client that comes with xcode and follow the instructions for using svn co on the google code site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This command worked for me:

```
svn checkout http://imedia.googlecode.com/svn/trunk imedia-read-only
```

Comment: Perfect, that's what I used. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want use command line, you can download and install TortoiseSVN.

Then create a empty folder and by right click on empty folder you should click SVN -> Checkout and paste this url:
http://imedia.googlecode.com/svn/trunk

Answer (score 1):

From http://code.google.com/p/imedia/source/checkout:

#### Command-line access

Use this command to anonymously check out the latest project source code:

> `# Non-members may check out a read-only working copy anonymously over HTTP.`
>    `svn checkout http://imedia.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ imedia-read-only`

#### GUI and IDE access

This project's Subversion repository may be accessed using many different [client programs and plug-ins](http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html). See your client's documentation for more information.

---

From [Getting Control with Subversion and XCode](http://developer.apple.com/tools/subversionxcode.html):

> Support for Subversion is built into Xcode (version 1.5 and later). However, you must create your Subversion repository and import your project into Subversion on the command line before managing it in Xcode. For detailed instructions on the use of Subversion, see the online book Version Control with Subversion which is endorsed by Subversion's developers.

(See the "Xcode and Subversion" section for more.)

See also: [Using Subversion in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1551886/using-subversion-in-xcode).

---

If you want to actually use Versions, see their [Support area](http://versionsapp.com/support):

1. [Bookmarking a repository](http://versionsapp.com/documentation/getting_started_bookmarkrepos.html)
2. [Checkout a working copy](http://versionsapp.com/documentation/getting_started_checkoutwcopy.html)
3. Start working