# Problems getting code examples from code.google.com

Tags: android

I am new to android and I am having a repeating problem when I find posts and the author has a like to where I am supposed to be able to download example code.  The latest example is the following URL where there is a post on how to use the ViewPager:

http://geekyouup.blogspot.com/2011/07/viewpager-example-from-paug.html

The author has a link to the following page where I am supposed to be able to download example code:

http://code.google.com/p/viewpagerexample/

But there is no code at this location.

This is happening over and over.  In fact every time I find a post where the author points to code.google.com I get an empty page.  What am I doing wrong?

Gary

Comment: I can see [the code](http://code.google.com/p/viewpagerexample/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FAwesomePager) just fine... you just have to look a bit for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is easily available on the very site you linked to. [Here](http://code.google.com/p/viewpagerexample/source/browse/#svn/trunk/AwesomePager%253Fstate%253Dclosed) is a more accurate link.

You can also check out the entire code by using the svn command:

```
svn checkout http://viewpagerexample.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ viewpagerexample-read-only
```

You must have [svn](http://subversion.tigris.org/) installed to do so, however.

Answer (score 0):

Code samples are included with the SDK. You can [use the SDK manager to install them](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/adding-packages.html), then look on your filesystem in `<<android SDK dir>>/samples/<<version>>/`.

Answer (score 0):

Please open your eyes :)

Click on the link source in the tab, and then you can checkout the code. And if you are too lazy to do this, you can click on the browse link, then go to the trunk folder, and then by following the arborescence of the project you can copy the code of the class by a simpliy copy/paste.

Comment: I come from a simpler world (MS) where if we want to download something we just hit the "download" button.  I find this android world much more arcane.  Another responder had the right answer: SVN

Comment: That was not so hard too see. Just google the question. Third result : How to get code from google code? on stackoverflow.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4683968/how-to-get-code-from-google-code