# Update core data

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I relased version 1 in appstore that contain coredata database , in version 2 I added new fields to the database how to modify dynamically the old database , with keeping the data

I already did without versioning and don't have the old version , and the application will crash on the customer ipad

any suggestion please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

take a look at the [Core Data Model Versioning and Data Migration Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: I already did the chnages and submitted the new version without versioning the application crashed in cutomer ipad any solution, versioning require the old model to be exists

Comment: If it doesn't matter that the data stored in the v1-app is lost after an update to v2 then you can just use another storeurl. Then coredata checks if the new storeurl exists (after an app-update it doesn't). If it not: CoreData will create the new model and everything is fine (except of data-loss from v1-store).

Comment: the data is matter , and it's a big problem , and what do u mean by storeurl

Comment: storeurl = path to the sqlite-db (if sqlite-type used). So data-loss is not what you want. afaik it is also possible to migrate without versioning. I think the automatic lightweight migration should work. Description can be found in the link I postet in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would encourage you to start using source control. XCode 4 has [SVN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1551886/using-subversion-in-xcode) and [Git](http://www.smartapps.co/2011/01/version-control-system-with-xcode-4-and-git-tutorial/) built in, you should give it a try - both are pretty easy to learn, and prepares you for when you need to have multiple people working on a project. Having your code in source control would have made this a straightforward problem to fix, you can get previous versions of any file at any point in time.

The [WWDC 2011 videos](http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011) have some good content on using source control effectively and efficiently as well.