# Using subversion across visual studio and Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, visual-studio, svn

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using Subversion in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1551886/using-subversion-in-xcode)

I'm building a cross platform application in Visual Studio (Win32/Win8/Direct3D) and Xcode (iOS/OpenGL). I have a repository working via Ankhsvn in Visual Studio but now I need to get the Xcode project connected to it. I've created a default Xcode OpenGL-ES project and will import functionality from the original project piecemeal, but I'm having the dickens of a time getting Xcode to work with the existing repository. Has anyone done something like this before? If so, do you have any pointers on how to do this?

Thanks!
Charlie.

Comment: OK, zip from SO, which is unusual. I'm going to try the following: (1) create a new project in Xcode (2) add it to my repository (3) bring in the actual code until it works, a bit (4) add in the Win32 elements manually (5) checkout the project in Visual Studio and hope it still works...